# Sorting by keyword in Kibana Discover

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

How can you sort data by a string value in Kibana Discovery (version `5.6.3`)? I would like to sort the rows `asc` by field `epoch.keyword`. Screenshot depicts the Kibana view below:

[image]

I've been experimenting with this function for a while, I've come to a conclusion that it isn't really achievable with the `Add a filter +` functionality either, nor have I found an explanation for this on Elastic forum. What the Elasticsearch documentation says about the `keyword` datatype:

> They are typically used for filtering (Find me all blog posts where status is published), for **sorting**, and for aggregations. Keyword fields are only searchable by their exact value.

...therefore I take it, that it's achievable - I've managed to get a working query, that returns properly sorted entries (grepped out relevant output for brevity):

```
curl -X GET 'http://<someurl>:<someport>/<someindex>/_search' --user <somecredentials> -d '{"query":{ "match_all": {} }, "sort":[{"epoch.keyword":{"order":"asc"}}]}' | python -m json.tool | grep epoch
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100  7569  100  7500  100    69  48622    447 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 48701
                    "epoch": "1510238524.255196",
                    "epoch": "1510238524.2578862",
                    "epoch": "1510238524.2595582",
                    "epoch": "1510238526.231628",
                    "epoch": "1510238526.2461028",
                    "epoch": "1510238526.2461133",
                    "epoch": "1510238526.2502348",
                    "epoch": "1510238526.2502463",
                    "epoch": "1510238526.2802055",
                    "epoch": "1510238526.2821074",
```

Index mapping:

```
{
    "<index-name>": {
        "mappings": {
            "doc": {
                "properties": {
                    "@timestamp": {
                        "type": "date"
                    },
                    "@version": {
                        "fields": {
                            "keyword": {
                                "ignore_above": 256,
                                "type": "keyword"
                            }
                        },
                        "type": "text"
                    },
                    "beat": {
                        "properties": {
                            "hostname": {
                                "fields": {
                                    "keyword": {
                                        "ignore_above": 256,
                                        "type": "keyword"
                                    }
                                },
                                "type": "text"
                            },
                            "name": {
                                "fields": {
                                    "keyword": {
                                        "ignore_above": 256,
                                        "type": "keyword"
                                    }
                                },
                                "type": "text"
                            },
                            "version": {
                                "fields": {
                                    "keyword": {
                                        "ignore_above": 256,
                                        "type": "keyword"
                                    }
                                },
                                "type": "text"
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "container_id": {
                        "fields": {
                            "keyword": {
                                "ignore_above": 256,
                                "type": "keyword"
                            }
                        },
                        "type": "text"
                    },
                    "container_name": {
                        "fields": {
                            "keyword": {
                                "ignore_above": 256,
                                "type": "keyword"
                            }
                        },
                        "type": "text"
                    },
                    "epoch": {
                        "fields": {
                            "keyword": {
                                "ignore_above": 256,
                                "type": "keyword"
                            }
                        },
                        "type": "text"
                    },
                    "fields": {
                        "properties": {
                            "logType": {
                                "fields": {
                                    "keyword": {
                                        "ignore_above": 256,
                                        "type": "keyword"
                                    }
                                },
                                "type": "text"
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "host": {
                        "fields": {
                            "keyword": {
                                "ignore_above": 256,
                                "type": "keyword"
                            }
                        },
                        "type": "text"
                    },
                    "message": {
                        "fields": {
                            "keyword": {
                                "ignore_above": 256,
                                "type": "keyword"
                            }
                        },
                        "type": "text"
                    },
                    "namespace": {
                        "fields": {
                            "keyword": {
                                "ignore_above": 256,
                                "type": "keyword"
                            }
                        },
                        "type": "text"
                    },
                    "offset": {
                        "type": "long"
                    },
                    "pod_name": {
                        "fields": {
                            "keyword": {
                                "ignore_above": 256,
                                "type": "keyword"
                            }
                        },
                        "type": "text"
                    },
                    "tags": {
                        "fields": {
                            "keyword": {
                                "ignore_above": 256,
                                "type": "keyword"
                            }
                        },
                        "type": "text"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How can I visualize the same query in Kibana Discovery?